# How to put an UserControl in Row details in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm watching at this link about how to show row details.

http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#rowDetails

I'd like to put an user control there. But I have no idea to do that. Supose that I have to show differents user control for each one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create various `DataTemplates` which contain instances of the `UserControls` you want in the `Resources` of the `DataGrid`, then you can create a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) which chooses the right one for you and set that as the [`RowDetailsTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplateselector.aspx).

**Edit:** Resource use example:

```xml
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
        <uc:ImageUserControl Source="{Binding Image}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GraphTemplate">
        <uc:GraphUserControl GraphData="{Binding Data}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Also make sure to read the [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but, how can I add them to resources? (The sintax)